# Export database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to export my database using php. I have seen this same question asked a few times here and in Google. However, everything I have tried has not worked. Here is what I currently have.

```
//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$dbname ='xxxx';
$dbuser ='xxxx';
$dbpass ='xxxx';
$dbhost ='localhost';
$backupFile = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").".sql"; 

exec("mysqldump --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpass --host=$dbhost $dbname > /home/xxxx/public_html/demo/coupons/tmp/$backupFile", $output);

Mage::log($output);
```

Shouldn't this work?

My log is empty:

```
2014-03-30T02:50:02+00:00 DEBUG (7):
```

It should contain a result?

Comment: Are you getting an error in your logs?

Comment: I have cron executing this code but I am not receiving any errors in my email and I do not see any error logs on the site. Nothing in the error logs in cPanel either.

Comment: Oh, for the `exec()` command, you might be able to get more details about what is going on by using the `output` parameter (see [this documentation for more details](http://us1.php.net/function.exec)...)

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code above but it is still empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry that it's still not working; are you able to run that `mysqldump` command manually to ensure that everything works on that side?

Comment: I'm using an script that i made by myself. I'm not saying it's the best, but it's working just fine. You can download it [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!C9ZQSb7C!7P_W1eImCJd8ryUF6WL08fTy4-JJZS8FsQR6NbyRhSI)

Comment: @summea Yah, I can use it with SSH just fine. Not sure what is wrong lol